# Filesystem object symbology

Tags: ruby

What is the most standard Ruby symbology for naming variables containing file names, file names with path and file instances? Completely clear way of doing this would be:

```
file_name = "bar.txt"
file_name_with_path = "foo", file_name
file = File.open( file_name_with_path )
```

But it's too long. It is out of question to use `:file_name_with_path` in method definition:

```
def quux( file_name_with_path: "foo/bar.txt" )
  # ...
end
```

Having encountered this for umpteenth time, I realized that shortening conventions are needed. I started making personal shortening conventions: `:file_name` => `:fn`, `:file_name_with_path` => `:fnwp`, `:file` always refers to a `File` instance, `:fn` never includes path, `:fnwap` means `:file_name_with_absolute_path` etc. But everyone must be facing this, so I am asking: Is there a public convention for this? More particularly, does Rails code have a convention for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But everyone must be facing this...

No, not really, because you're really over-thinking this.

Just use `file:`, or `filename:`. It *doesn't matter* whether your filename contains a relative or absolute path, or whether the path contains directories, and your code should reflect this. A path to a file is just a path to a file, and all paths should be treated identically by your code: It just opens the file, and raises an error if it can't.

You can use filesystem utilities to extract directories and base names from a path, and they'll work just fine on *any* path, regardless of the presence of directories, regardless of wether the path is absolute or relative. It just doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 for confirming my own suspicion that I'm overthinking it. Yet, [Ruby docs consistently](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html) use `file_name`...

Comment: Then pick `file_name` instead of my suggested `filename`. The point is, you don't need *different* names for relative/absolute/directory-containing paths.

Comment: There is something into what you just said.